# PCA algorithm makes iris dataset to be reversed on y axis

Tags: python, data-science, pca

I am making PCA in python with this code:

```
def OWN_PCA(X,num_components):

  #Step-1
  X_meaned = X - np.mean(X , axis = 0)
     
  #creating covariance matrix
  cov_mat = np.cov(X_meaned,rowvar=False)

  #calculating eigenvector and eigen value
  eigen_values , eigen_vectors = np.linalg.eigh(cov_mat)

  #sorting the vectors based on eigen values
  sorted_index = np.argsort(eigen_values)[::-1]
  sorted_eigenvalue = eigen_values[sorted_index]
  sorted_eigenvectors = eigen_vectors[:,sorted_index]

  #choosing number of components
  eigenvector_subset = sorted_eigenvectors[:,0:num_components]

  X_reduced = np.dot( eigenvector_subset.transpose(), X.transpose() ).transpose()

  return X_reduced
```

The problem is when I apply it to the iris dataset and plot it, I will get this:
[image]

and when I use PCA in sklearn the image is reversed:
[image]

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Probably nothing, I think PCA gives you a set of perpendicular dimensions but the direction along one of the axis is completely arbitrary.